# Can I use ETCD over Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, etcd, etcd3, etcd2

I want to store some data in Key/Value format. I am looking for some solution which should be highly available and faster. I know that ETCD is distributed reliable key-value store. What I am not able to figure out is should I use ETCD or Cassandra when my primary objective is only to store data.

Answer (score 3):

[Etcd](https://etcd.io/docs/v3.3.12/learning/why/) has the quintessential use case of storing metadata in a distributed system.

It will not be best suited as a primary database because -

- It lacks data sharding.
- Doesn't support all kinds of data types. Clients will have to handle based on their needs.
- Supported maximum volume (~ 8GB)

A lot depends on your use case. It can be used but may not be a best fit.